# Load dataframe too large for system memory from jld2 file

Tags: julia

I have a file "myfile.jld2" which contains a `DataFrame`, say `mydata`. Is it possible to load `mydata` in some way although it doesn't fit into system RAM?

I only want to load it to split it up into smaller pieces and dump those to disk.

Comment: AFAIK JLD2 does not support it, but you could try treating it as HDF5 and reading only a portion of it, see https://support.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/Tutor/selectsimple.html.

Comment: Another option (not Julian, but this is what I do in such situations): rent out an AWS instance with 1 or 4 TB  of RAM, run the split code, export the data to S3, dump (terminate) the instance.

Comment: That's what I thought, thanks.

Comment: @PrzemyslawSzufel Thanks for the suggestions. I used an external usb drive as memory cache extension and loaded the file (slowly).